# Is there a way to save money by disabling SMS and routing to IM?

Tags: messages, sms

I.e., could I configure a client such as AIM, Jabber, Skype, etc. on my phone and completely switch off SMS altogether?

Would the sending party be alerted that their SMS won't go through?

Answer (score 2):

I cancelled my SMS plan and use iMessage with people who have iPhones and Google Voice with people who don't. Both are free.

I can still receive SMS messages, but I get charged for them (but it's exceedingly rare that I get one). My wife opted to block all SMS messages. If someone sends one to her they do not get any notification that it is not received.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should have expected that about no notifications that SMS is blocked. I've found that the textPlus is a pretty good app and system: free phone number for incoming SMS's. There are also a couple apps that provide this for Google Voice numbers.